# Connection to sql server from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am new to asp.net which are all files should use to connect a sql server please help me. If anyone knows tutorials please send a link.  Thanks in advance

Comment: just google it you can find lot of tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using C# for code behind;
There are three thing you have to look into

1. Connection String :- Which tell the application what's the name of database,    in which server; and user login credential
2. Is Connecting the server with Asp.net app
3. Here you can use ADO.net; Create a connection object and open it and do you process.

Folloe this one its very good http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet

Comment: what is the difference between asp.net and ado.net

Comment: ADO.net is a part of Asp.net; which deals data connection and handling